# How do you add query parameters to a Dart http request?

Tags: http, get, dart, flutter, url-parameters

How do you correctly add query parameters to a Dart http get request? I been unable to get my request to respond correctly when trying to  append the '?param1=one&param2=two' to my url, yet it works correctly in Postman. Here's the gist of  my code:

```
    final String url = "https://www.myurl.com/api/v1/test/";
    String workingStringInPostman = "https://www.myurl.com/api/v1/test/123/?param1=one&param2=two";

    Map<String, String> qParams = {
     'param1': 'one',
     'param2': 'two',
    };


   var res = await http
      .get(Uri.encodeFull("$url${widget.pk}/"),
      headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Token $token", 
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"},
);
```

The ${widget.pk} is simply a integer value being pass (See the value 123 in the workingStringInPostman variable.

The qParams is there for connivence, in case a Uri parameter is needed.

A code example would be welcomed.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You'll want to construct a `Uri` and use that for the request. Something like

```
final queryParameters = {
  'param1': 'one',
  'param2': 'two',
};
final uri =
    Uri.https('www.myurl.com', '/api/v1/test', queryParameters);
final response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Token $token',
  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
});
```

See https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Uri/Uri.https.html

Comment: The splitting up of the host and path was the answer.

Comment: for some reason, the application stops after `Uri.https` like an exception, but without error, it just stops.

Comment: Got error if the url is local host with port like `localhost:5001`.

Comment: not working for local address define path of api

Comment: To create a URI for a `localhost` address. `Uri.http('localhost:5001', '/api/v1/whatever', {'param1': 'one'})`. If you are hitting issues with `https` and localhost it could be a certificate issue.

Answer (score 51):

this is more simple

```
final uri = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/v1/endpoint').replace(queryParameters: {
      'page': page,
      'itemsPerPage': itemsPerPage,
    });
final response = await client.get(uri);
```

Comment: this is very easy for the HTTP package not for the Dio package.

Comment: Doesn't work properly it adds only the first two query params

Answer (score 38):

If you dont want to override the scheme of base endpoint url, use the below technique to convert the map to query string and append it to the base endpoint url

```dart
var endpointUrl = 'https://www.myurl.com/api/v1/user';
Map<String, String> queryParams = {
  'param1': '1',
  'param2': '2'
};

var headers = {
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Token $token',
  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
}

String queryString = Uri.parse(queryParameters: queryParams).query;

var requestUrl = endpointUrl + '?' + queryString; // result - https://www.myurl.com/api/v1/user?param1=1&param2=2
var response = await http.get(requestUrl, headers: headers);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore. An error is thrown at `http.get(requestUrl....)`

`The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.`

Comment: @OjonugwaJudeOchalifu just wrap the String in Uri.parse().

Comment: I don't see any parameter `queryParameters` of Uri.parse

Comment: Parameter `queryParameters` does not exists in `Uri.parse()`

Comment: instead of Uri.parse() use Uri(queryParameters: queryParams)

Answer (score 8):

Got the same question. The accepted answer won't work if my url is localhost with port like `https://localhost:5001`. After spending 1 day to search for solution, I come up with [Dio library](https://pub.dev/packages/dio). Following is my solution using `Dio`:

```dart
var _dio = new Dio();
var options = new Options;
options.headers['Authorization'] = 'bearer $token';
options.contentType = 'application/json';
String url = "https://www.myurl.com";
Map<String, String> qParams = {
  'param1': 'one',
  'param2': 'two',
};

var res = await _dio.get(url, options: options, queryParameters: qParams);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: getting this error still - Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (12741): Receiver: null
E/flutter (12741): Tried calling: []("BankName")

Comment: can you suggest any solution?

Comment: In order to get a response as a `List<String>`, I had to do `_dio.get<List<dynamic>>(...).data.cast<String>();`. If somebody knows a better way, feel free to let me know.

Comment: It should be `options.headers = {'Authorization': 'bearer $token'};`

Answer (score 6):

Use `Uri` constructor to build your query, it has a `queryParameter` property.

```
var uri = Uri(
  scheme: 'https',
  host: 'example.com',
  path: '/foo/bar',
  fragment: 'baz',
  queryParameters: _yourQueryParameters,
);

var response = await http.get(uri);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
  // Do whatever you want to do with json. 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `Uri` to pass query parameters like.

```
final String url = "https://www.myurl.com/api/v1/test/${widget.pk}/";

Map<String, String> qParams = {
 'param1': 'one',
 'param2': 'two',
};
Map<String, String> header = {
HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Token $token", 
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"
};

Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
final finalUri = uri.replace(queryParameters: qParams); //USE THIS

final response = await http.get(
  finalUri,
  headers: header,
);
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer didn't work for me but adding a '&' without quotes to end of the URL solves my problem. In this case, change the following line:

```
String workingStringInPostman = "https://www.myurl.com/api/v1/test/123/?param1=one&param2=two";
```

to this: (Notice the '&' at the end).

```
String workingStringInPostman = "https://www.myurl.com/api/v1/test/123/?param1=one&param2=two&";
```

Comment: Most simple and best solution)

Answer (score 2):

There is a dart package that provides some helper classes for http requests.

BasicUtils : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils

Install it with:

```
dependencies:
  basic_utils: ^1.4.0
```

Usage

You can add a map of headers and query parameters to each request. See the example :

```dart
// Define some headers and query parameters
Map<String, String> headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json"
};
Map<String, String> queryParameters = {
  "foo": "bar"
};

// Body
String body = "{ 'some':'json'}";

// Send request
Map<String, dynamic> responseData = await HttpUtils.postForJson("api.com/dosomething", body,
      headers: headers, queryParameters: queryParameters);
```

Additional information :

These are all methods from the HttpUtils class.

```dart
Future<Map<Response> getForFullResponse(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getForJson(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> getForString(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<Response> postForFullResponse(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postForJson(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> postForString(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Response> putForFullResponse(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> putForJson(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> putForString(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Response deleteForFullResponse(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> deleteForJson(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> deleteForString(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Map<String, dynamic> getQueryParameterFromUrl(String url);
String addQueryParameterToUrl(String url, Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function copied from flutter code can be used to create the query string part only:

```
String queryString(Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters) {
  var result = StringBuffer();
  var separator = "";

  void writeParameter(String key, String? value) {
    result.write(separator);
    separator = "&";
    result.write(Uri.encodeQueryComponent(key));
    if (value != null && value.isNotEmpty) {
      result.write("=");
      result.write(Uri.encodeQueryComponent(value));
    }
  }

  queryParameters.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value == null || value is String) {
      writeParameter(key, value);
    } else {
      Iterable values = value;
      for (String value in values) {
        writeParameter(key, value);
      }
    }
  });
  return result.toString();
}
```

Usage:

```
var q = queryString({"a":"b&", "c":["1","xyz"]});
// a=b%26&c=1&c=xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little util function which resolves the `authority` / `unencodedPath` parameters for `Uri` creation.

```
Uri createUri(String url, [Map<String, String> queryParameters]) {
  var isHttp = false;
  if (url.startsWith('https://') || (isHttp = url.startsWith('http://'))) {
    var authority = url.substring((isHttp ? 'http://' : 'https://').length);
    String path;
    final index = authority.indexOf('/');

    if (-1 == index) {
      path = '';
    } else {
      path = authority.substring(index);
      authority = authority.substring(0, authority.length - path.length);
    }

    if (isHttp) {
      return Uri.http(authority, path, queryParameters);
    } else {
      return Uri.https(authority, path, queryParameters);
    }
  } else if (url.startsWith('localhost')) {
    return createUri('http://' + url, queryParameters);
  }

  throw Exception('Unsupported scheme');
}
```

Here is the example code which uses it:

```
final String url = 'https://www.myurl.com/api/v1/test/${widget.pk}';
Map<String, String> qParams = {
  'param1': 'one',
  'param2': 'two',
};

var res = await http.get(
  createUri(url, qParams),
  headers: {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Token $token",
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use this:

```
String _getParamsFromBody( Map<String, dynamic>? body) {
String params = '?';
for (var i = 0; i < body!.keys.length; i++) {
  params += '${List.from(body!.keys)[i]}=${List.from(body!.values)[i]}';
  if (i != body!.keys.length - 1) {
    params += '&';
  }
}
log(params);
return params;
```

}

```
Uri.parse("https://www.myurl.com/api/v1/test"+ _getParamsFromBody({'param1':'value1','param2':'value2}))
```

Comment: Beware! This approach does NOT escape the query parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
  final uri = Uri.parse("${ApiConstants.baseUrl}/blog/post/blog-post-list");
  uri.replace(queryParameters: {"location": location});
  final Response response = await _apiRepository.getApi(uri);
  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
    final content = await jsonDecode(response.body);
    final data = await content["data"] as List;
    List<PostModel> list = [];
    for (var i in data) {
      final postModel = PostModel.fromJson(i);
      list.add(postModel);
    }
```

this works as of today

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me.

```
  _init() async {
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.now();
    DateTime startDate = endDate.subtract(Duration(days: 30 * 11));
    var response = await Api.get(
        "mover/dashboard/column-chart?start=$startDate&end=$endDate");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }
```

Api.dart

```
  static Future<http.Response> get(path) async {
    String? token = await Store.read('token');
    try {
      var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('$basePath/api/moving/$path'),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      );
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      return http.Response('${err.toString()}', 400);
    }
  }
```