# Dart - sending GET parameters that are lists

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I want to send parameters with an http GET request in dart. The first answer here demonstrates it well: [How do you add query parameters to a Dart http request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52824388/how-do-you-add-query-parameters-to-a-dart-http-request)

```
var uri =
    Uri.https('www.myurl.com', '/api/query', queryParameters);
```

However, a major problem is that queryParameters only accepts:

```
Map<String, String>
```

**This doesn't allow me to pass in lists/arrays.**

If i change my get request to a post request, I am easily able to send a 
body (as a json encoded String) as outlined by the flutter docs: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html

```
post(url, {Map<String, String> headers, body, Encoding encoding})
```

However, the get request has no such equivalent argument for query parameters: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html

```
get(url, {Map<String, String> headers})
```

I have also tried adding query parameters directly to the url like so:

```
get('www.myurl.com/api/query/?array[]=value1&array[]=value2&array[]=value3)
```

but the square brackets [] always get transformed into %5B%5D when I receive it in the server.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact, `queryParameter` takes `Map<String, dynamic>`. Check the source code:

```
  factory Uri(
      {String scheme,
      String userInfo,
      String host,
      int port,
      String path,
      Iterable<String> pathSegments,
      String query,
      Map<String, dynamic /*String|Iterable<String>*/ > queryParameters,
      String fragment}) = _Uri;
```

The `dynamic` can be either a `String` or an `Iterable<String>`. So,

```
  var uri = Uri(
    scheme: 'http',
    host: 'www.myurl.com',
    path: '/api/query/',
    queryParameters: {
      'array': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    },
  );
  print(uri);
```

prints:

```
http://www.myurl.com/api/query/?array=value1&array=value2&array=value3
```

Comment: That `[]` suffix is a kludge for PHP servers. Doesn't the server accept the URL encoded form? (The only place in a URL that unescaped bracket is allowed is an IPv6 address.)

Comment: whoops i just deleted my comment since i realized my server was reading %5B%5D as []. So everything is now working well. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .toString on the list itself :

note : used http package  >  **http: ^1.1.0**

```
  List<double> location = [lat, long];

  final uri = Uri.parse(API.BASE_URL + API.searchAPI).replace(queryParameters: {
    'searchText': searchQuery,
    'userLocation': location.toString(), //here
  });
```