# Handle body of request API in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

To use api in flutter apps I usually use https url with different keys. But I want to know how can I use an api like the following

[image]

It has request url but also something called request body. How can I use it in flutter. And how can `request body` be used with url.
Is there any flutter package that can help me?.

Can you give an example code of how url will look??

Comment: try this package https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: @JideGuru How can I use fields in request body in this package

Answer (score 0):

use http package `https://pub.dev/packages/http` to get request or post request to an api. It will send response back and then can use `jsonDecode` to decode json string. 
Check out this article for step by step explanation
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Comment: Can you give an example code of how url will look? The article talks about simple url passing that I know. I just can't understand what these request body fields are.

Comment: You can get and post data using body of that request which is generally a json object if you want to send data using url  then use `queryParameters` option in dio and http package. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52824388/how-do-you-add-query-parameters-to-a-dart-http-request