# error in query parameters when send get request type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to send data with queryParameters in get request but i get this error
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

```
var UriData = Uri.parse(base_url_data + api_url);
  final dataa = {
    "Protocol":"jsonPTS",
    "Packets":[{
      "Id":"1",
      "Type":"ReportGetPumpTransactions",
      "Data":{
        "Pump":"1",
        "DateTimeStart":"2019-05-19T12:45:14",
        "DateTimeEnd":"2019-05-19T13:45:14"
      }
    }]
  };
  final newURI = UriData.replace(queryParameters: dataa);

  print(newURI);
  return http.get(
    newURI,
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  );
```

Comment: what is expected URL do you want?

Comment: https://demo.raitotec.com/api/ +ReportGetPumpTransactions

Comment: try this example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52824562/12838877

Answer (score 1):

in the above coder replace

```
 final newURI = UriData.replace(queryParameters: dataa);
```

with this:

```
 final newURI = UriData.replace(queryParameters: jsonEncode(dataa));
```

**EDIT**

to send data body as a raw-data you can try this:

```
        var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(''));
    request.body = json.encode({
    "Protocol": "jsonPTS",
    "Packets": [
        {
        "Id": "1",
        "Type": "ReportGetPumpTransactions",
        "Data": {
            "Pump": "1",
            "DateTimeStart": "2019-05-19T12:45:14",
            "DateTimeEnd": "2019-05-19T13:45:14"
        }
        }
    ]
    });
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    }
    else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
```

Comment: error The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Comment: which line is causing the first issue?

Comment: final newURI = UriData.replace(queryParameters: dataa);

Comment: how to send data in body in get request

Comment: you want to send raw data?

Comment: i not found how to send data in body in get request , i try to send in queryparameters but it return error when send list in queryparameters

Comment: there are several ways in which we can send data in body one is "raw" one is "form-data" one is "binary" now i dont know how are you sending it

Comment: show me how can send as raw json data in get request